# HTTP to HTTPS on aws elastic beanstalk not working for Spring Boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get http -> https working with elastic beanstalk, and their documentation doesn't seem to be working. I've set up the load balancer to terminate http and https successfully.

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

both work.

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html) explains how to configure https to http redirects. I'm using java-se with Spring Boot, so I've read [the readme](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/java-se) and placed `.ebextensions` in my `src/main/resources` folder.

So my finished spring boot jar has `myapp.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf` with:

```
location / {
     set $redirect 0;
     if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
       set $redirect 1;
     }
     if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
       set $redirect 0;
     }
     if ($redirect = 1) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }

     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

inside it. But nothing redirects to https.

Comment: Can you edit .httpacess?

Comment: @Ismael You mean like logging into the load balancer's server and changing it manually? I could in theory, but then it wouldn't work automatically, and I'd have to manually redo that if I had another environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out! Put `.ebextensions` in the root folder of your project, not `src/main/resources`. Then add the `bootJar` command to stick that folder at the top level of the finished jar, where it needs to be for AWS to pick it up:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    bootJar {
        from('.ebextensions') {
            into('.ebextensions' )
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you to the answer to this question for getting me the rest of the way there:

[How do you build a folder into the .jar root of a spring boot gradle project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54175340/1313268)