# How do you build a folder into the .jar root of a spring boot gradle project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

AWS elastic beanstalk requires a `.ebextensions` folder at the root of your jar to configure elastic beanstalk, but I can't figure out how to get a folder to the root of the jar.

With this gradle config I can change the location of a folder:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    processResources {
        from ('.ebextensions/') {
            into '.ebextensions'
        }
    }
}
```

That moves the folder `.ebextensions` from the root of my project (not `src/main/resources`) to

```
my.jar
 -> BOOT-INF
    -> classes
       -> .ebextensions
```

I was hoping I could just make it `into '../../.ebextensions'` but that doesn't work. Is this just impossible? Do I need to figure out how to manually unpack the jar, insert my folder, and then repack it or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can configure gradle task called `bootJar` by following way:

```
bootJar {
     from('.ebextensions') {
        into('.ebextensions' )
     }
}
```

[Packaging executable jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars) says:

> Executable jars can be built using the `bootJar` task. The task is automatically created when the java plugin is applied and is an instance of BootJar. The assemble task is automatically configured to depend upon the `bootJar` task so running assemble (or build) will also run the bootJar task.

Or alternatively you can configure `jar` task:

```
jar {
     from('.ebextensions') {
        into('.ebextensions')
    }
}
```

[Packaging executable and normal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal)

Comment: Thanks so much! Changing `bootRepackage` to `bootJar` (apparently they changed the name) and `'./.ebextensions'` to `'.ebextensions'` did the trick. `processResources` still put it in the wrong place, and `jar` didn't work either.